# Silverlight/WP7: programmatically change the button background image

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

```
<Button x:Name="BtnSearch" Height="120" Width="120" Margin="-20,-30,0,0" Click="BtnSearch_Click" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Visibility="Visible" >
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="searchImage" ImageSource="images\appbar.feature.search.rest.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Button.Background>
```

In the above xaml I have to change the imagesource programmatically to a different image. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach you can use is [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/14/creating-round-image-button-for-wp7-part-1.aspx). Since your question does not specify the action the code takes to change the background, therefore, you may have to adapt the code in the referred link a bit. Note that you may have to return the ImageBrush from the converter, if you intend to go down the path suggested in the post.

HTH,
indyfromoz

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
searchImage.ImageSource =

        new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgPath, UriKind.Relative));
```

to change the image associated with background image brush.

Comment: @ Vinay But by using this code i get the button color to transparent when clicked