# How can I get stop the button control in Windows Phone from making that ugly white flash when clicked?

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, click, imagesource

So I have a few items in a list that I display on my MainPage. I have a button that looks like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" BorderThickness="0" Height="40">
     <Button.Background>
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WindowsPhonePanoramaApplication2;component/Images/appbar.feature.email.rest.png" Stretch="None" />
     </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Every time I click on it, the image disappears under this bright white rectangle. I'd rather have it display another image instead. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for looking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight/WP7: programmatically change the button background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797304/silverlight-wp7-programmatically-change-the-button-background-image)

Comment: Try an invisible button:

   http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366713/1821686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll need to retemplate the button to use a different visual state when clicked.

See also these following image button controls/alternatives:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2011/04/22/using-images-as-buttons-on-windows-phone-7.aspx
- http://web.archive.org/web/20110209105722/http://www.silvergeek.net/windows-phone-7/imagebutton-control-for-win-phone-7/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/14/creating-round-image-button-for-wp7-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the button template. You can find the template within the file here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Design\System.Windows.xaml
```

The `ButtonBase` template is as follows:

```
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Note how the `Pressed` `VisualState` changes the background of the `ButtonBackground` element (i.e. the `Border`) to `PhoneForegroundBrush`. This is what makes your button turn white.

You can create your own button template, changing the image within the `Pressed` state. Search the web if you are not sure how to create your own control template.

Answer (score 0):

This Question is a year old. However, here is the perfect way to achieve what you want. I see that you want to simulate the same experience similar when you press  the appbar icon.

The [Coding4fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RoundButton&referringTitle=Documentation) toolkit has the exact ailment you need.

Here is how the code would look like,

```
<c4fControls:RoundButton Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" 
    ImageSource="/Myapp;component/Images/appbar.img.png"/>
```

[image]

Ofcourse, you would have to include the coding4fun library to your project. Add this line to the top of the page as well.

```
xmlns:c4fControls="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls"
```